# Why do I get Invalid parameter: redirect_uri when logging into a realm admin console?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I've just setup Keycloak on Kubernets. Its working as expected only I have to port-forward into the Pod to access the web UI. If I access it from the internet as soon as I land on the login page I get the error `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri`

I get this accessing both the master and my application realm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Keycloak allows non-HTTPS communication over private IP addresses like
>   localhost, 192.168.x.x, and other private IP addresses.

You might need to setup  HTTPS/SSL

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#setting-up-https-ssl

Comment: Thanks. I enabled `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` and that did the trick.